# Winform (C#) App's Graphics Quality/Colors changes during run time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

As you see can in the pictures Design time colors and run time colors are different. (Looks like it changes to a lower color scheme). I don't have any coding that affects the visuals.

[image: Design Time]
[image: Run Time]

Comment: That looks like visual styles are not enabled. If it's a .NET Framework project, is there a call to `Application.EnableVisualStyles` in the `Main` method? What does the `Main` method look like either way?

Comment: What is the `FlatStyle` of the `Button` set to? How exactly did you make the parent that grey colour? Is it on an MDI parent form or did you just set the `BackColor` of the parent?

Comment: If Visual Styles are actually enabled, what version of Visual Studio are you using and what is te Project's .Net version?

Comment: Hi Hasala Senevirathne, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered.
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

As [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18877258/john) mentioned calling visual styles method fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As John said. The project does not have visual styles enabled. There is such a line of code in the Main method of every C# Winform project.

```
 //Visual style for launching the application

 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

Comment: If John said that, then why are you adding an answer saying what John already said?